# Error in Docker for Windows tutorial

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker so I don't even know where to look. Here are the instructions:

> Next, pull a base image that’s compatible with the evaluation build, re-tag it and to a test-run:
>
> ```
> docker pull microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.321
> docker tag microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.321 microsoft/windowsservercore
> docker run microsoft/windowsservercore hostname
> 69c7de26ea48
> ```

And this is the error I get on the `docker run` step:

> docker: Error response from daemon: container
>   6abd92755a8d5d13463eb74f9cc39a798ad0ec898bc1f80ff71205235b63a94f
>   encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows
>   system call: No hypervisor is present on this system. (0xc0351000)
>   extra info:
>   {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"6abd92755a8d5d13463eb74f9cc39a798ad0ec898bc1f80ff71205235b63a94f","Owner":"docker","IsDummy":false,"IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\6abd92755a8d5d13463eb74f9cc39a798ad0ec898bc1f80ff71205235b63a94f","Layers":[{"ID":"17e4231d-380e-5dae-b734-0182defea00c","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\1226fe85e49abd361df8019342eec380ab577268565d2f3d813adcf37d1ccac4"},{"ID":"5fd42877-5043-5d33-a842-d70584cb03eb","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\53f86340ec419aae07b48e3624d00d7d6f5491f284d8d6e1e62fb7909d9a5fba"}],"HostName":"6abd92755a8d","MappedDirectories":[],"SandboxPath":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["91c8a929-c40f-4ad3-a3d2-2906b51cb50a"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\1226fe85e49abd361df8019342eec380ab577268565d2f3d813adcf37d1ccac4\UtilityVM"},"Servicing":false,"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}.

Comment: I have verified that the Hyper-V and Containers features have been turned on at the OS level.

Comment: Did you check the "virtualization" flag at BIOS level? It depends on your BIOS but generally it is an option about cpu settings in BIOS.

Comment: Yep. I'm running in a VM, so I know that's set correctly. Are there any VMWare settings I need to know about?

Comment: you mean windows itself is running in a vm? Can you run a vm in that vm? I know it can be tricky to get hyper v working inside a vm, but it should be possible in vmware.